# Messenger bot using Rails: setup for multiple pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to create a Messenger Bot used by different users for their Facebook pages. I created a rails app and use the [facebook-messenger gem](https://github.com/jgorset/facebook-messenger).

I successfully created the bot and it works when I do the set up for one page. Now, I follow the instructions to make my bot live on multiple Facebook Pages (see ["Make a configuration provider" section](https://github.com/jgorset/facebook-messenger#make-a-configuration-provider)).

I'm new to rails and I'm not sure where to put the class ExampleProvider? I put it in my config/application.rb file:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module BotletterApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    config.paths.add File.join('app', 'bot'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb')
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'bot', '*')]
  end

  class BotProvider < Facebook::Messenger::Configuration::Providers::Base
    def valid_verify_token?(verify_token)
      bot.exists?(verify_token: verify_token)
    end

    def app_secret_for()
      ENV['APP_SECRET']
    end

    def access_token_for(page_id)
      bot.find_by(user_id: page_id).page_access_token
    end

    private

    def bot
      MyApp::Bot
    end
  end

  Facebook::Messenger.configure do |config|
    config.provider = BotProvider.new
  end
end
```

Then I have my app/bot/setup.rb file to create the bot. I don't know how to use the provider I created in place of the ENV variables?

```
require "facebook/messenger"

include Facebook::Messenger

Facebook::Messenger::Subscriptions.subscribe(access_token: ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN"])

Facebook::Messenger::Profile.set({
  get_started: {
    payload: 'GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD'
  }
}, access_token: ENV['ACCESS_TOKEN'])
```

I searched in the Rails documentation how to make it work but unfortunately could not find anything.

UPDATE:

Now I'm able to set up the bots for different pages. Unfortunately, the following line of my ConfigProvider is getting an error:

config/initializers/config_provider.rb

```
def bot
    Rails.application.class.parent::Bot
  end
I'm getting the following error:
```

> NameError (uninitialized constant BotletterApp::Bot):
>
> config/initializers/config_provider.rb:17:in bot'
>   config/initializers/config_provider.rb:7:inapp_secret_for'

Do you know how should I name my app?

My BotModule:

```
module BotletterApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    config.paths.add File.join('app', 'listen'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb')
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'listen', '*')]
  end
end
```

UPDATE, it works with ::Application, here is the new file:

```
class ConfigProvider < Facebook::Messenger::Configuration::Providers::Base
  def valid_verify_token?(verify_token)
    ENV['VERIFY_TOKEN']
  end

  def app_secret_for(page_id)
    ENV['APP_SECRET']
  end

  def access_token_for(page_id)
    CoreBot.find_by_page_id(page_id).page_access_token
  end

  private

  def bot
    BotletterApp::Application
  end
end

Facebook::Messenger.configure do |config|
  config.provider = ConfigProvider.new
end
```

The problem is I get the following error unless my db query seems working (it works in the rails console):

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:
>   page_id.id: SELECT  "core_bots".* FROM "core_bots" WHERE
>   "page_id"."id" = ? LIMIT ?):

Comment: Just wondering: why are you using Rails to run this gem. Your app will be much lighter if you skip the Rails part and just use plain ruby + rack (as suggested in the gem's [README.md](https://github.com/jgorset/facebook-messenger/blob/master/README.md)). Typically you'd place a class like BotProvider in `lib/bot_provider.rb`, though.

Comment: I'm using a rails app because I need to build a dashboard to help my users manage the settings of the bot, sign up etc. It's easier than doing it in NodeJs or plain ruby

Comment: Ok, then it makes sense :) Have you already made a model that contains the codes? `rails g model bot access_token app_secret verify_token page_id:integer` ... the MyApp::Bot is expected to be something like an ActiveRecord::Model, which implements `exists?` and `find_by`

Comment: Yes, I already created the database and the models.

Comment: And you placed the BotProvider in lib? what errors are you getting?

Comment: Don't try to make it overly generic, just write: BotletterApp::Bot instead of Rails.application ... but that's not the problem. It can't find the class 'Bot' in the module BotletterApp... try if plain `Bot` works. 

btw. if you've found an answer to your initial question, you can post it below.

Comment: What do you mean by "try if plain Bot works"?

Comment: By the way, I added the module BotletterApp, indeed there is no bot class in it...

Comment: It works with ::Application, I updated the question

Comment: Regarding 'plain'... Instead of 

    def bot
      BotletterApp::Application
    end

use

    def bot
      Bot
    end

Comment: It seems it's working! Thanks. But I still get the error mentioned at the bottom of the updated question. That's weird, my db query works well in the Rails console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to an answer for improved readability ;)

Regarding 'plain'... Instead of

```
def bot
  BotletterApp::Application
end
```

use

```
def bot
  Bot
end
```

or (it looks like you named your model containing all pages CoreBot(?) (assuming you have a typical ActiveRecord model in `/app/models/core_bot.rb`, I was assuming `Bot`)

```
def bot
  CoreBot
end
```

Then you should be able to use the template code from the [README.md](https://github.com/jgorset/facebook-messenger/blob/master/README.md)

As for your latest problem: it seems like the `access_token_for`-method gets called with a hash, searching with something like `{id: 1}`. You might want to check where that value is coming from. I would suggest to take a few steps back, and stay closer to the template code.

Comment: It works well! The right way to write the method was "CoreBot.find_by_page_id(page_id['id']).page_access_token"